# Remove a widget item with an Ajax callback (in an entity browser widget)

Tags: 8, ajax

**[edit to add]**:

1-The ajax callback is made from a field (`field_company`) inside the regular `user_form`

2-The logic and the callback definition reside inside the `hook_form_alter` of the `user_form` => maybe this is my problem

**[-----]**

-A "Companies" dropdown `field_company` allow to select a company

-When a company is selected, an Ajax Callback is fired

-The Ajax Callback return the "Buildings" widget (each company have one or more building). When clicking on this "buildings" widget (entity browser), I get only the list of the buildings of the selected company which is what is expected.

Until this, everything works fine. I am using the '#widget_context' key to filter the buildings and the user is allowed to select one of them.

But, If the user wants to change the selected company, I have to remove any selected building in the "buildings" widget.

Here is my failing Ajax callback code:

```
function company_select_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $form['field_buildings']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value'] = "";
    //Rebuid do not works $form_state->setRebuild(true);
    return $form['field_buildings'];
}
```

Comment: The things you try to do in the ajax callback are normal form logic which belongs in the form build and submit handlers. BTW also the setRebuild() which only makes sense in a submit handler.

Comment: @4k4 I understand your comment regarding the setRebuild(), thank you. For the remaining, my only goal is to remove one item (if any) of `field_building` [single value field] at **each** ajax callback. The widget is `entity browser`... and I didn't succeed.

Comment: Can't help you with the specific issue, but you need to find another place to modify $form.

Comment: This is the regular `user_form` and I put my logic into the `hook__form_alter`... maybe this is why it is not working...

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the fact that the ajax definition is made in a `hook_form_alter` function.

Comment: To update my first comment, the form alter hook is part of form building, so there you could put the form logic or add a submit callback to a form element containing the action you want when the element is triggered.